# How to construct regex to identify dollar ($) money sum

Tags: python, regex, dollar-sign

I'm trying to create a regex that can identify sum of money (in dollars). 
The problem is that the data is generated by OCR on scanned PDF files, so the data is not precise:

- `$` can be represented by `S`
- `.` can be represented by `,`
- `1` can be represented by `l` or `I`
- `5` can be represented by `S`

Examples:

```
Data:       What is should be:
S0.01    => $0.01
S1       => $1
S400.05  => $400.05
$0,01    => $0.01
S0,SI    => $0.51
```

**Question:** Is it possible to construct a regex that can search for such a complex pattern?

Comment: Regex can be used to find $ but only at the end of a line

Comment: Please clarify. Do you want a regex that identifies OCR-scanned money amounts, or do you want code that replaces "S", ",", "I", etc with the appropriate digits and characters? "matching" and "replacing" are very different things.

Comment: Both are trivial, but false positives can't be avoided with regular expressions alone.

Comment: @wim: could you elaborate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not that complex. Start with a regular expression that can match "pristine" output, something like

```
\$[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{2})?
```

Now, just replace the questionable characters with their alternatives.

```
[$S][0-9SIl]+([.,][0-9SIl]{2})?
```

This can give you false positives, as you will "find" `$1` in a sentence like "I read SI for baseball and basketball news" (SI being an abbreviation for the magazine *Sports Illustrated*, but that's unavoidable with regular expressions alone.

Once you've made the match, *converting* the result to its assumed correct form is simple: replace any initial `S` with `$`, any `,` with `.`, and any other `S` with `5`.

Comment: You just forgot `l` in both character classes `[$S][\dIlS]+(?:[.,][\dIlS]+)?`.

Comment: I did; I nearly forgot `I` in the first draft as well :)